# Pine script: the correct bar number is not displayed for pivot points

Tags: count, pivot, pine-script

I have written a Pine script that displays the number of each bar/candle and of selected pivot points.
However, the number at the pivot points differs from that of the respective bar, although I use the same variable. In my opinion, the bar number should be the same as the pivot point number, but it isn't.

This is incomprehensible to me. Is there a way to correct this?

(Hint: I need the correct pivot point number in order to process it further in the script).

```
//@version=5
indicator('(_) number of bars and pivot points', overlay=true, max_labels_count = 500)

// --- input ---------------------
lenPivot = input.int(defval = 28, title = 'Pivot lenghts', minval = 1)
// --- pivot ---------------------
pivotH = ta.pivothigh(high, lenPivot, lenPivot)
pivotL = ta.pivotlow(low, lenPivot, lenPivot)
// --- count ---------------------
countDays() =>
    DoW = dayofweek
    na(DoW[1]) or DoW != DoW[1]
var counter = 1
if countDays()
    counter := 1
else
    counter += 1
// ----- labels ------------------
LabelBar = label.new(bar_index, 0, text = str.tostring(counter), yloc = yloc.belowbar, 
     style = label.style_none, textcolor = color.orange, size = size.normal)
if not na(pivotH) 
    LabelPivotH = label.new(bar_index[lenPivot], pivotH, text = str.tostring(counter), 
         color = color.new(color.red, 050), style = label.style_label_down, 
         textcolor = color.black, size = size.small)
if not na(pivotL) 
    LabelPivotL = label.new(bar_index[lenPivot], pivotL, text = str.tostring(counter), 
         color = color.new(color.green, 050), style = label.style_label_up, 
         textcolor = color.black, size = size.small)
```

My goal:
Display the number of bars at the respective pivot point, calculated back from the last bar (bar_index). This can easily be calculated by: last bar number minus pivot point bar number.
However, this assumes that the pivot point bar number is correct - which is not the case with my script.

Answer (score 0):

`countDays()` is a function that returns true whenever it detects a day change.

`counter` is a variable with a default value of 1, incremented by one on every bar. Every time a day change is detected, its value is reset to 1.

Underneath each candle, you print the current value of `counter`. I see no issues with this label. Given that you print the current value of `counter` under each candle, the labels under the candles will show the correct value of `counter`.

The problem is with the labels you print for pivot high/low detections. Pivot detection is a lagging exercise, which means `pivotH` or `pivotL` will only have a value other than `na` once `lenPivot` many bars have formed since the bar marking the pivot. Therefore, when you print the pivot high/low labels, you must print them in the past (`lenPivot` candles to the left).

But when you print a label in the past, you also need to ensure you use a historical value of `counter`; the value of the `counter` variable was at `lenPivot` bars ago.

Therefore, instead of printing the current value of `counter`:

```
text = str.tostring(counter)
```

You should print its value `lenPivot` candles ago:

```
text = str.tostring(counter[lenPivot])
```

Here is the corrected version of your script.

```js
//@version=5
indicator('(_) number of bars and pivot points', overlay=true, max_labels_count = 500)

// --- input ---------------------
lenPivot = input.int(defval = 28, title = 'Pivot lenghts', minval = 1)
// --- pivot ---------------------
pivotH = ta.pivothigh(high, lenPivot, lenPivot)
pivotL = ta.pivotlow(low, lenPivot, lenPivot)
// --- count ---------------------
countDays() =>
    DoW = dayofweek
    na(DoW[1]) or DoW != DoW[1]
var counter = 1
if countDays()
    counter := 1
else
    counter += 1
// ----- labels ------------------
LabelBar = label.new(bar_index, 0, text = str.tostring(counter), yloc = yloc.belowbar, 
     style = label.style_none, textcolor = color.orange, size = size.normal)
if not na(pivotH) 
    LabelPivotH = label.new(bar_index[lenPivot], pivotH, text = str.tostring(counter[lenPivot]), 
         color = color.new(color.red, 050), style = label.style_label_down, 
         textcolor = color.black, size = size.small)
if not na(pivotL) 
    LabelPivotL = label.new(bar_index[lenPivot], pivotL, text = str.tostring(counter[lenPivot]), 
         color = color.new(color.green, 050), style = label.style_label_up, 
         textcolor = color.black, size = size.small)
```

Comment: Hi, your explanation makes perfect sense. The historical value of 'counter' was the problem. Simple, actually. I just had an error in my thinking. Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: Two - additional - questions (if you like to answer it):
 
1. i would like to save the individual pivot values in an array. Unfortunately, I can only do this with the last pivot value. 
 
2. the difference between bar_index and the bar count of the last pivot value results in a value that is recognized internally as a 'series'. Unfortunately, I cannot convert this value into an absolute value (constant) in order to process it as a constant value in the further course of the script.
 
Is there any workaround or trick to accomplish this?